# Как смержить два массива/объекта c приоритетом?

Tags: javascript

Вообщем есть два конфига:

```
const config1 = {
     app_name: 'app',
     app_dir: 'app/'
     modules: [
         {name: 'module1'},
         {name: 'module2'},
     ]
};
```

и

```
const config2 = {
     app_name: 'app_local',
     modules: [
         {name: 'module1'},
         {name: 'module3'},
     ],
};
```

Нужно их как-то смержить в один, с учетом того что второй имеет больший приоритет т.е. должно получится:

```
  const config3 = {
     app_name: 'app_local', // из второго конфига т.к. у второго приоритет выше,
     app_dir: 'app', // из первого т.к. у второго нет такого поля
     modules: [
         {name: 'module2'}, // из первого конфига т.к. у второго нет такого объекта
         {name: 'module1'}, // из второго конфига т.к. у второго приоритет выше
         {name: 'module3'}, // из второго конфига т.к. у второго приоритет выше
     ]
  };
```

Comment: с массивом непонятно. Как Вы определяте есть/нет "такой" объект - полное совпадение всех названий свойств и их значений?

Comment: Будь это коллекции - можно было бы просто добавить во вторую всё из первой, игнорируя ошибки дублирования ключа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день, я хочу дать немного расширенный ответ на ваш вопрос.
Он будет работать и тогда когда у вас разное количество объектов в подмассиве `modules`:

Допустим у нас есть такие входные данные:

```html
    <script>
        const config1 = {
            app_name: 'app',
            app_dir: 'app/',
            modules: [
                {name: 'module1'},
                {name: 'module2'},
                {name: 'module4'},
            ]
        };
        const config2 = {
            app_name: 'app_local',
            modules: [
                {name: 'module1'},
                {name: 'module3'},
            ]
        };

        function merge_arr(arr1,arr2){

            arr = Object.keys(arr1).map(function (key) {
                if(typeof arr1[key] === "object" && !(arr1[key] instanceof Array)){
                    if(typeof arr2[key] === 'undefined'){
                        arr2[key] = arr1[key];
                    }
                    else                    
                        merge_arr(arr1[key],arr2[key]);
                }
                else{
                    if(arr1[key] instanceof Array && arr2[key] instanceof Array){
                        var tmp_arr = [];
                        var max_length = 0;
                        if(arr2[key].length > arr1[key].lengt){
                            tmp_length = arr1[key].length;
                        }else{
                            max_length = arr1[key].length;
                            tmp_length = arr2[key].length;
                        }
                        for(var i=0;i<tmp_length;i++){
                            if(JSON.stringify(arr2[key][i]) !== JSON.stringify(arr1[key][i])){
                                arr2[key].push(arr1[key][i]);
                            }
                        }
                        if(max_length !=0 && max_length != tmp_length){
                            for(var i=tmp_length;i<max_length;i++){
                                arr2[key].push(arr1[key][i]);
                            }
                        }                    
                    }
                    else{                    
                        if(typeof arr2[key] === 'undefined'){
                            arr2[key] = arr1[key];
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }
        merge_arr(config1,config2);
        //Во втором массиве после вызова функции будет объединение двух массивов с критерияами который вы хотели.
        console.log(config2);
    </script>
```

Я написал рекурсивную функцию что бы смог пройтись по всему объекту.
Функция имеет два входных параметра, которые в этом случае ваши константы.
И в каждой итерации сделано несколько типов сравнений, поскольку у вас наложены друг в друга и `array` и `object`. А сравнения простые, каждый раз если во втором входном объекте нет поля который есть в первой я его добавляю в второй входной объект.